# Getting certain text after tag with jsoup

Tags: html, text, tags, jsoup

Hi I am trying to get certain text from HTML file using jsoup. I already know how to get text2 and text3. But how do I get text I want without others?

```
<div class="snt"> text I want  
<br clear="both" />text2  
<br clear="both" />text3  
<br clear="both" />  
</div>
```

I tried to use

```
Elements lines = doc.select(".snt");
lines.First().nextSibling().toString();
```

but I get nothing. I also tried:

```
Elements lines = doc.select(".snt");  
lines.text(); // this return all texts together
```

Can you please help me? Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try ownText() for the first element you will get "text I want text2 text3" and this is correct. You want the text before br and this is the first child node under your first element. Jsoup handles text as a node.

```
Elements lines = doc.select(".snt");
System.out.println(lines.first().childNodes().get(0));
```