# How can I extract the data from this html using jsoup

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

I am developing an android app in which I have to show daily hadith. I have a link on which hadith is updated daily. Here is the backend html of that page.

```
<div class="hadith-explanation" id="hadithcontent">
<h2>Today's Hadith</h2>
<br>
<h3>Commitments</h3>
<br>
<p>The Messenger of Allah (sal Allahu alaihi wa sallam) said: "He has (really) no faith who fulfills not his trust,
   and he has (really) no religion who fulfills not his promise." [Baihaqi]<br /><br />Always keep your word.
   Each time you keep a commitment you are rewarded by Allah (subhana wa ta'ala) for obeying Him. If you mix a few drops of wine in a glass
   full of water, it spoils the whole glass of water and makes it unfit for consumption. Similarly, dishonesty in any sphere of your life
   permeates and corrupts your entire nature and eeman. When a person&rsquo;s words carry no weight, it only reveals his/her treacherous nature.
   <br /><br />If you promise to be somewhere, make sure you are there on time. If you promise to call somebody back, do so on time. Don't commit
   what you cannot do. One minute means 60 seconds everywhere, no more. Make a habit of under-committing rather than over-committing.<br /><br />
   The online version of Daily Hadith is available. Please visit http://dailyhadith.adaptivesolutionsinc.com
</p>
```

I want to get the data starting from paragraph tag till the first br tag. i.e starting from 'The Messanger of Allah..' till [Baihaqi].

I have searched on web and found out that it can be done using jsoup library but I dont have much programing knowledge about it. Some one please guide me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [childNodes()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodes--).

Java:

```
package com.github.davidepastore.stackoverflow33780189;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

/**
 * Stackoverflow 33780189
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("file.html");
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(is, "UTF-8", "");
        Element element = document.select(".hadith-explanation p").first();
        String result = element.childNodes().get(0).toString();

        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

file.html:

```
<div class="hadith-explanation" id="hadithcontent">
    <h2>Today's Hadith</h2>
    <br>
    <h3>Commitments</h3>
    <br>
    <p>
        The Messenger of Allah (sal Allahu alaihi wa sallam) said: "He has
        (really) no faith who fulfills not his trust, and he has (really) no
        religion who fulfills not his promise." [Baihaqi]<br />
        <br />Always keep your word. Each time you keep a commitment you are
        rewarded by Allah (subhana wa ta'ala) for obeying Him. If you mix a
        few drops of wine in a glass full of water, it spoils the whole glass
        of water and makes it unfit for consumption. Similarly, dishonesty in
        any sphere of your life permeates and corrupts your entire nature and
        eeman. When a person&rsquo;s words carry no weight, it only reveals
        his/her treacherous nature. <br />
        <br />If you promise to be somewhere, make sure you are there on
        time. If you promise to call somebody back, do so on time. Don't
        commit what you cannot do. One minute means 60 seconds everywhere, no
        more. Make a habit of under-committing rather than over-committing.<br />
        <br /> The online version of Daily Hadith is available. Please visit
        http://dailyhadith.adaptivesolutionsinc.com
    </p>
</div>
```

[A similar case here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205641/getting-certain-text-after-tag-with-jsoup).